# How to disable unnecessary services starting at boot in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, 18.04, services

I have disables the boot animation in my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, now I can see all the services(such as snap, postgresql, mongodb etc.) that are loaded during the boot process. 
Some of the them are programs that I have installed and rarely used. They Take a lot of time to load and slows the whole booting process.

Is there a way to identify the processes Ubuntu comes pre installed?
Then I can disable the other processes from booting.

Comment: It's good that you have found a s0lution.. But your question is about disabling the services.. Where as you ended up with removing packages.. Kindly edit the question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see which service takes how long to start during system boot, you can run `systemd-analyze blame`. This will give you a list of services sorted by how long it took to start each service. From there, you can see if there's anything you don't need on your system and disable it with `sudo systemctl disable`.

Answer (score 1):

If you install stuff using the command line rather than the software center, you could look at your `apt` cache to see what you've manually installed yourself, and then remove any you no longer need:

`cd /var/log/apt`

In this folder, there will be a series of files which end in `.log` (recent, uncompressed text files) or `.log.<num>.gz` (zipped files). You want `history.log` and any `history.log.<num>.gz`. You'll need to manually go through them.

To see pachages you've manually installed in the zipped files, you can use:

`zcat history.log.1.gz | grep installed`

For the uncompressed logs you can use:

`cat history.log | grep installed`

You can then work your way through the output, uninstalling what you don't need. When you're done, run:

`sudo apt autoremove`

Which will remove any dependencies of the packages you removed that are no longer needed.