# Find out which services are safe to stop from starting up on system boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, startup, services

I have an ubuntu 18.04 and I've installed some applications like mongodb, kubernetes, docker, etc. Now my system is really slow when booting up and sometimes it freezes when I'm working.
I don't use some of these applications very often so I want to stop them from running.

How can I find out which services are safe to remove from starting up on the system boot and which ones will cause trouble for my system?

Comment: There is a very similar question with an answer already here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218013/how-to-disable-unnecessary-services-starting-at-boot-in-ubuntu-18-04/1218030#1218030

Comment: Thank you, I've already cleared my apt history so I get nothing when I follow those steps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Stacer downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Center.

There is an option to observe which Startup Apps you have set with an option to turn them on and off at will so you can investigate issues further.

[image]